# Error Loading Main Class in Java in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: java, windows, cmd, runtime

I am trying to run an image compression code in Java, and after a long time I am not using an IDE to do so, and am running the code from windows cmd itself.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class Compression {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

      File compressedImageFile = new File("compress.jpg");
      OutputStream os =new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

      Iterator<ImageWriter>writers =  ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
      ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

      ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
      writer.setOutput(ios);

      ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

      param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
      param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);
      writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

      os.close();
      ios.close();
      writer.dispose();
   }
}
```

In cmd I am in the directory where the Compression.java is present. 
This is what is happening:

[image]

Any suggestions? I have tried all the suggestions given on Stack on similar questions but none of them seem to work for me.

Comment: Is your class inside a package?

Comment: Current directory is not in the classpath, by default. Use `java -cp . Compression`.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: No my class is not inside a package.

Comment: @AashimaYuthika can type `dir/s` and show the output ?

Comment: @Andreas: Much Appreciated! It worked. But when I was learning Java initially this problem never occurred, even though I was in the current directory. I even tried setting the path using "set path" but that did not work either. Any idea why that might have happened?

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code into a new file, created the Compression.java file, saved it, then used `javac Compression.java` and then `java Compression` and the class was executed (I got an issue since I cannot find the files).

Comment: @AashimaYuthika You needed to set CLASSPATH, not PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you showed the full code, your class is not in a package, so that's not the issue.

Your issue is likely that the current directory is not in the classpath, by default. Check it with this command:

```
set CLASSPATH
```

To run your code directly, use:

```
java -cp . Compression
```

This will run Java with the current directory as the only path in the classpath.